# MongoDB Dynamic $in

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, npm, mongodb-query

Is there a way to dynamically send a list of string to a `$in` clause for MongoDB?

I tried something like the code below, but it doesn't work and I haven't been able to find more info other than an example that has the values hardcoded.

The `restrictedUsers` variable can be populated with any number of users, so I can't hardcode this.

**Example**:

```
var restrictedUsers = "bob, joe, jimmy, roger, greg";
userNames = {"usernames": { $in: [restrictedUsers]}};   
collection.find(userNames);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is wrong with using an array:

```js
var restrictedUsers = [ "bob", "joe", "jimmy", "roger", "greg"];

userNames = {"usernames": { $in: restrictedUsers }};

collection.find(userNames);
```

Even if for some reason you have a string that is seperated by comma's, splitting that up into an array is fairly trivial:

```js
var userList = "bob, joe, jimmy, roger, greg";  
var restrictedUsers = userList.split(',')
```